# How to transliterate ASCII control characters to their UTF-8 symbolic equivalent?

Tags: c++

I want to transliterate any character in the control character range (0x00 NUL to 0x1F) to the Unicode *symbol* for that character encoded as UTF-8. Do you have a simple/elegant solution in C++?

Example:

Rather than print '\n' in the string, replace it with the 'N-L' control symbol, and do this for all unprintable characters.

```
␋␌␍␇␍␑␌␔␈␘␕␖ʬ␄␓␕␊
```

- [ASCII Characters](http://plato.asu.edu/MAT420/beginning_perl/3145_AppF.pdf)
- [Unicode 2400 Control Characters](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2400.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string ReplaceASCIIControlCharacters(std::string input)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> output;
    output.reserve(input.length());
    for (char c : input) {
        if (c >= 0x00 && c <= 0x1F) {
            output.push_back(0xe2);
            output.push_back(0x90);
            output.push_back(0x80 + c);
        } else {
            output.push_back(c);
        }
    }

    return std::string(output.begin(), output.end());
}
```

### Commenter's suggested improvement

```
std::string output;
output.reserve(input.length()); 
for (char c : input) { 
    if (c >= 0x00 && c <= 0x1F) {         
        output.append({0xe2, 0x90, 0x80 + c}); 
    } else { 
        output.push_back(c);
    } 
} 

return output;
```

Comment: Or `output.assign(output.end(), {0xex, 0x90, 0x80+c});` - could be slightly more efficient.

Comment: @MSalters there is no overload of [`string::assign()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/assign) that takes those parameters. I think you meant [`string::insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) instead. Or even just [`string::append()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append).

Comment: May I ask why are you using a temporary `vector` instead of building directly the returned string?

Comment: OK - so the idea here is that I would provide a sketch of an answer and someone else would answer it - ideally in a better way. I just hacked this - at the moment I needed to do it as PoC. I do not intend to accept my answer as the Canonical answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, that was indeed the intent.

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer doesn't get much simpler than what you have presented. Though, like Bob suggested, you don't need the `vector` at all: `std::string output; output.reserve(input.length()); for (char c : input) { if (c >= 0x00 && c <= 0x1F) { output.append({0xe2, 0x90, 0x80 + c}); } else { output.push_back(c); } } return output;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am not a regular C++ programmer and my style tends to be rather naive. So I'm glad to see any improvements.

Comment: Shouldn't you also handle DEL (0x7F) ?